# Filter row by a vector on single character field with more then one possible hits

Tags: r, vector, filter, tidyverse

I'm in trouble... with an R script:

Given a tibble and a character vector

```
tbEsempio <- tibble(C1 = c(100,150,200,343,563), C2 = c("A", "A&B", "D", "D$C", "E"))
vcValori <- c("A","B","C")
```

I need filter tbEsempio on C2 with values in vcValori vector.

If I use `%like%` without vector it is ok:

```
tbEsempioFiltered <- tbEsempio[which(tbEsempio$C2 %like% "A" | 
                                     tbEsempio$C2 %like% "B" |
                                     tbEsempio$C2 %like% "C" )]
```

but using vcValori with `%in%` operator instead `%like%`

```
tbEsempioFiltered <- tbEsempio %>% filter(C2 %in% {{vcValori}})
```

the line with 2 (or more) values separate by "&", in the exemple is 2 and 4, are not included.

There is a solution using tidyverse framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)

tbEsempio %>% 
  filter(grepl(paste(vcValori, collapse = "|"), C2))
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     C1 C2   
  <dbl> <chr>
1   100 A    
2   150 A&B  
3   343 D$C
```

Comment: seems to work as expected,
Thank you